# I am sending a json object from angular to python API, but I don't know how to get it in python API

Tags: python, angularjs, json

Angular code

```
var  headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type' , 'application/json');
var link_arr_json={'match_with':'sdkf','arr':['ag','sdf','sdf']};
var send_Data = "data="+JSON.stringify(link_arr_json);
return  this.__http.post(api_link,send_Data,{headers: headers})         
.map(response =>    response.json());
```

Don't know how to receive this object in python api,like we get other variables send by post request using request.form['variable_name']

data is like this below, array cant have value 1 to 100s

```
var link_arr_json={'match_with':'sdkf','arr':['ag','sdf','sdf']};
```

In API I am just trying to receive values, other processes are working well.

Comment: Please extend your question with the data to send and information about the "python api".

Comment: formatting, spell check

Comment: have you tried `request.body`?